# bing maps ajax v7 clustering

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, markerclusterer

I am trying to create Bing map clustering similar to what Google offers. However, the only docs I found from an "official" source (http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2011/03/01/bing-maps-v7-modular-design-and-client-side-clustering/) have a broken link to the actual code.

Does anyone know where to get the supported Bing clustering module?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search gives an open source available at codeplex:http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Client%20Side%20Clustering.

Comment: thanks @phpdna-- I did see that but scanned past it since the downloads tab was empty. I thought it was a placeholder / discussion article.

Comment: The download tab is only optional. Codeplex is mainly a git repo. I looked in the repo and it seems to me there is something in the trunk but you need git!!??

Comment: I wrote that module. The version on CodePlex is the most up to date version and works well. You can download the code from the source code tab. In the past I used to have zip files on each module page, but those downloads didn't register on the download counter. The client side clustering module is used by tens of millions of users every day. I wrote the original version about 7 years ago. I have a more recent blog post on this here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/clustering-pushpins-in-windows-store-apps2/

Comment: @rbrundritt-- thanks! and thanks for your work creating the module.